# wordpress installation with sql server express edition

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-server-2008, web-deployment, sql-server-express

I have developed a web portal in wordpress using xampp server. I have my database in MySQL.

I now need to deploy this wordpress portal on another system with Microsoft SQL Server Express edition.

So how can I deploy it successfully with SQL server and what software or driver or service will be needed for this deployment on the system?

I have already tried to export my SQL database in MSSQL compatible format, and import it into SQL server but it is not executing.

Please help me?